# Wrong (generic) Mac dock application icon

Tags: high-sierra, dock, icon

I have the following problem since upgrading to OS X 10.13.1 High Sierra on MBP 2017.  A generic icon is shown for nearly all my apps. See the image below. Does anyone know how to fix this and get the applications icons back?

[image: desktop]

Comment: seems to be epidemic... https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/307773/most-program-icons-look-the-same-after-high-sierra-update

Comment: Booting in safe mode solves this. I wrote an more detailed answer on this duplicate questions: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/308674/35889

Comment: Just in response to "Marked as duplicate" and being very pedantic about it ;) , I think I asked the question first (on Dec 4th versus Dec 5th) so therefore the other question is the duplicate!!!! Just my immature childish side peeking through...I'll get over it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running this shell script `sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: if I can find the Terminal icon ;)

Comment: tried it but no joy

Comment: You'd probably need to reboot afterwards.

Comment: Actually it worked for local login but it still is an issue for my network login (ie to my company network). I’ll check if rebooting works and accept answer if it works but we’re half way there! I’ll get back to you in this...

Comment: I tried it it in both local login and domain login, but it only worked for my local login, generic icons still exist in my company (domain) login.

Comment: Another of these cropped up today - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308058/icons-not-appearing-on-high-sierra - with a terse answer, "reboot in safe mode". Might be worth a shot, just so we can try to tie down what seems to be a common problem.

Comment: Reboot in safe mode was actually the first thing I did before coming to Stackexchange. Maybe I should have initially said this in my question but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: When I started my Mbp this morning some of the icons had reverted back to the generic icon again!

Comment: I re-rebooted in Safe mode and problem fixed. Why it took a few reboots I don’t know but problem solved

Answer (score 1):

1. Recursively descend the directory tree for `/private/var/folders/` path and remove any file named `com.apple.dock.iconcache`:

   ```
   sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm {} \;
   ```
2. Recursively descend the directory tree for `/private/var/folders/` path and remove any file named `com.apple.iconservices`:

   ```
   sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.iconservices -exec rm -rf {} \;
   ```
3. Kill the `dock` process:

   ```
   killall Dock
   ```

Comment: Heh, this made even _more_ icons disappear for me. I suppose it was bound to happen, the next time I restarted.

Comment: Recent OS X's, e.g. High Sierra, have System Integrity Protection turned on by default; these commands, even with sudo, do NOT remove the wanted files/directories.  You have to turn off SIP before; the easy way is to boot in recovery mode, start the Terminal, type these commands (of course "killall Dock" is not needed) and reboot in normal mode.  That worked for me.

Comment: I also added `touch Applications/*` and `find Applications -name Info.plist -exec touch {} \;` before rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

Running Disk Repair out of Recovery Mode resolved this issue for me. Reboot while holding Command-R. Select Disk Repair from the menu. Select and Unmount Macintosh HD (if necessary). Select First Aid and run it. Restart from the Apple Menu.