# Icons not appearing on High Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, icon

I updated to High Sierra on my Macbook Pro when it was released.
Since I have updated, a lot of my applications show the attached icon when I open them.
Does anyone know a fix to this?

[image]

Comment: Can you give some examples of the applications that are showing the icon?  A screen shot perhaps?

Comment: There should be a screenshot of the icon attached to the post. The problem seems to be unrelated to the apps being used and are seemingly random.

Comment: Definitely an epidemic - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/307773/most-program-icons-look-the-same-after-high-sierra-update & https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/307861/wrong-generic-icon-for-apps

Comment: I tried using the terminal commands someone suggested in another thread, however I get "Operations not permitted"; unsure why that is happening.

Comment: sudo requires an admin password

Comment: Would the admin password be the local computer admin or another admin? I used my admin password and was unsuccessful still.

Comment: local admin; anyone one the sudoer's list

Comment: Hm.. not sure why mine failed then...

Comment: I have League Of Legends installed and i have this problem aswell!

Answer (score 6):

Give this a try.

```
sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.iconservices -exec rm -rf {} \;
sudo rm -rf /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store
killall Dock
```

After running the commands, I had to remove the app from the dock and add it again. It worked for me but YMMV.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

Rebooting in "Safe Mode" fixes this issue. Probably because system caches are cleared and re-created during safe boot.

To boot in Safe Mode, hold the <kbd>shift</kbd> key while starting or rebooting the Mac. You can release the shift key when the login prompt appears.

Apple provides more details about Safe Mode in [this article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262).

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did, but it resets your dock to default and removes every app expect the default ones:

```
$ defaults delete com.apple.dock
$ killall Dock
```

Don't know if it lasts long but I got all the icons back.

Comment: This kills the settings of my dock, and the icons don't still come back.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have the game "League of Legends" installed on your Mac ?

Other persons having this problem have reported that the update process of League of Legend may cause this issue.

If so, please upvote this issue on the LoL forum, to report it to developers : https://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/bug-report/rA0p1rYx-client-updating-on-mac-high-sierra-messes-up-other-application-icons

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem - reboot your mac in safe mode and then it will resolve itself

Comment: This fixed the problem for me initially (icons on the dock were not missing after rebooting in safe mode and rebooting a second time), but later on when re-opening applications the issue has re-emerged.